# What is the best way to block ocsp.apple.com on mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, big-sur

There seems to be some bug where mac os is constantly contacting http://ocsp.apple.com. You can prevent it by turning off the wifi, but then your computer is nothing more than a fancy calculator. Is there a program, vpn, or even the firewall option, to block this site from the whole os?

Comment: I've been using Little Snitch for **years** to prevent outgoing connections I don't want. But I would bet some firewall-hacking-experts might know a free method...

Comment: You could just turn off GateKeeper with `sudo spctl --master-disable`.

Comment: On Thursday, 8 November 2020 around 4pm ET, many Mac users were unable to launch applications because Apple's servers were overloaded. This thread has solutions to  block GateKeeper and prevent a recurrence. The original thread that directed me to this one is: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406398/how-to-diagnose-sudden-and-fleeting-hang-of-computer

Comment: It should be noted that disabling OCSP, may leave your machine vulnerable to malware.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A quick and easy solution is to use your system's hosts file to redirect requests to localhost.

```bsh
sudo sh -c 'echo "127.0.0.1  ocsp.apple.com" >> /etc/hosts'
```

Then you'll want to make sure this has been applied by clearing the DNS cache - which on the latest version is done by forcing the DNS responder to restart:

```bsh
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Comment: I'm getting `-bash: $: command not found`. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: I haven't tested this to confirm, but if Apple decides to use DNS over HTTPS, this won't work at all

Comment: @DisplayName The `$` is just the prompt, the command part starts with `sudo`

Comment: @Allan If DNS over HTTPS is implemented at the OS-level, changes to the hosts file should still apply AFAIK. It's my understanding that the only reason it doesn't at the moment is because DoH is usually implemented by browser vendors such as Firefox who avoid using any OS-level DNS resolution, hence ignoring the hosts file.

Comment: @Sam starting in Big Sur, Apple is starting to make it impossible to disable their monitoring tools. The new API prevents apps like LittleSnitch from blocking the traffic and it will even "go around" a  VPN if you have one. It's not a major leap to ignore the hosts file and do DoH resolution directly from `trustd` to prevent users from circumventing things.

Comment: @Allan You do make a good point and naturally Apple sees their monitoring tools as a security protection and therefore bypassing them could be considered a vulnerability particularly with a potentially untrustworthy VPN, however I believe it is unlikely that the hosts file would be ignored as unlike programs or VPNs blocking checks to Apple's servers it is blatantly obvious if someone is abusing the hosts file because a user can trivially see both that it's been modified and how it's been modified.
Either way it's a useful workaround for the present.

Comment: @Sam I totally agree that it's a worthwhile fix for the present (thus my +1 on this answer).  I'm merely pointing out that Apple can break this given that they already "broke" LittleSnitch's ability to block traffic coming out of your own computer.

Comment: @Allan For sure, while I don't necessarily think they will, you're totally right that they can break this. In which case doing this at the router-level like your answer suggests would, of course, be an ideal "Apple-proof" solution. That said something like a piHole may also be necessary as not everyone has commercial grade routers - or even access to the router they use, e.g. college networks.

Comment: @SamJakob - check out pfSense... commercial grade for free and on hardware that most people would toss out as rubbish!  On  [r/pfSense](https://www.reddit.com/r/PFSENSE/) users literally take it as a challenge to see how cheap they can build a router.  Saw one a while back on an R-Pi.

Comment: How do you undo this?

Comment: @archieoi The easiest way is probably to edit the `hosts` file (`sudo nano /etc/hosts`) and delete the line. Then, save the file and exit. You can run `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` to ensure the changes are applied immediately.

Answer (score 7):

The best way is to block it at the Internet gateway as you won't be successful blocking locally it at the machine.

Big Sur has apparently got a new API that prevents apps like Little Snitch from blocking those connections and will even circumvent your VPN

Source:  [sneak.berlin](https://sneak.berlin/20201112/your-computer-isnt-yours/)

> The version of macOS that was released today, 11.0, also known as Big Sur, has new APIs that prevent Little Snitch from working the same way. The new APIs don’t permit Little Snitch to inspect or block any OS level processes. Additionally, the new rules in [macOS 11 even hobble VPNs so that Apple apps will simply bypass them.](https://appleterm.com/2020/10/20/macos-big-sur-firewalls-and-vpns/)

So, if Apple makes Little Snitch useless and even bypasses your VPN to call home to report what, where, when and even how you use your Mac then the only way to do this is at the network gateway.  So, while Apple can force the *machine* to behave the way it wants, it still has to send packets over the network.  Block all outgoing traffic at the *router* to http://ocsp.apple.com and there's nothing Big Sur can do about it.

#### Using pfSense.

I'm a big proponent of using "commercial grade" routers and networking gear even in the home.  pfSense makes some excellent hardware appliances but their firewall software is available for download, for **free**.  You just need a cheap core 2 duo PC (small form factor is best, but any desktop or tower will do), a small SSD (32GB is more than enough) and an additional NIC card (quad Ethernet cards can be had for less than $50USD).  This will give you a very efficient router using the same firewall software enterprises use.

**Step one:  Identify the IPs needed to block.**  Simply pinging ocsp.apple.com will give you their IP - 17.253.13.206.  However, there are probably fallbacks so an `nslookup` would be advisable (`nslookup ocsp.apple.com` and it yields two more IPs - 17.253.13.207 and 17.253.13.201.

**Step two:  Create an alias to reference this list of hosts.**  pfSense allows you to have aliases to individual hosts, a list of hosts, and even whole networks.  The benefit here is that you can write the rule once and as the networks change and evolve over time, all you have to do is edit the alias and not the rule.  Below is a screen capture of the alias configured in pfSense for all three hosts.

[image]

**Step 3:  Write the LAN rule to block/reject the traffic.**  Simply create the LAN rule to block any connections to OCSP alias (list of hosts).  The source can (and should) be "any," but you could configure this for just one Mac or any/all Macs behind the firewall.  Use both IPv4 and IPv6 to ensure all your bases are covered. Same with TCP and UDP.  Below is the rule summary screen showing this configuration.

[image]

**Step 4:  Apply the changes**.  You may find in your testing (as I did) that `nslookup` didn't provide all the hosts and there's apparently a range of IPs from 17.253.13.201 through .207.  pfSense allows you to select ranges by using the syntax:  17.253.13.201 - 17.253.13.207 and it will auto generate each host.  To test, simply ping using the DNS name or any of the the IP addresses in the range.

Optionally, you can have these attempts logged as well (you can even do this prior to blocking) so you can see every time your Mac(s) reach out and call home and using optional plugins like [Snort](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/packages/snort/setup.html) you can capture the actual packet data and see what's being transmitted (and received).

Comment: Setting the router to block a specific destination URL is easy, but will only work if the data stream is one way (machine > Apple server). If the Apple server sends a response when data is submitted, the lack of response could trigger unpleasantness. Are these submissions truly unidirectional?

Comment: The question @DavidSupportsMonica is *how do you block it* not what are the ramifications.  That's [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/406353/119271) that's already asked.

Comment: I get 17.253.55.204, 17.253.55.206 and 17.253.55.208, so blocking the range is recommended.

Comment: Yes, mine is a different question. The referenced other question has been asked — thanks for the pointer — but its answer is still opaque, at least to me.

Comment: What's opaque about it @DavidSupportsMonica?

Comment: A better word would be "unresolved." Nohilside's comment to your answer, and your response, indicates that we don't know — yet — what consequences might appear from the computer's not reporting in.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Once again...what you're referring to is outside the scope of the question.  If you see it as "unresolved" that's because I didn't answer it due to it not being asked. Nohillside's comment says he got *more* IPs and his suggestion to use IP ranges which is something I specifically and preemptively addressed in step 4.  It has nothing to do with "ramifications."  Why are you hold this answer to a standard not scoped but completely ignoring the accepted answer which essentially does the same thing but locally on the machine?

Comment: Sloppiness. You're right again. I'll give some thought to writing a question about consequences,

Comment: @Allan is manipulating the hosts file not sufficient?

Comment: @MartinMlostek - read the second through fourth paragraph of the answer.  It's literally the "why" to the answer.

Comment: @Allan well, I did that, maybe I was unclear. I was just wondering if - on my local mac - it is sufficient to edit the /etc/hosts file as outlined here in case you cannot setup a pc-in-the-middle to filter the traffic

Comment: It should  be sufficient until it is bypassed by Apple at which point it won't be anymore.  This solution doesn't allow Apple ignore your wishes