# How to diagnose sudden and fleeting hang of computer?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, performance, zoom.app

Two days ago, I launched a Zoom meeting with the Zoom client. The client launched but did not show a GUI window and did not respond. I tried from the browser and both Google Chrome and Chromium had the same problem:

[image: Zoom, Chrome, and Chromium not responding]

I restarted the computer and had the same problem with Zoom and Brave. When I launched Brave multiple times, I saw this window: `You can't open the application "Brave Browser.app" because it is not responding.`:

[image: Non-responding alert]

I shut it down with the power-on button and still had the same problem. Other programs that did launch, such as VLC and Emacs were very slow and took about 2 minutes, then they worked OK. I checked CPU usage with `top -o cpu` and no program was using a lot of it. I thought it may be a loss of a memory chip, and shut it down.

The two days after, the computer was once again working normally. The last time I updated Zoom was more than a week ago (and I had used it without issues the day before); Chromium, Chrome, and Brave was 28 days before; `macOS` was before that. I did not update programs after that and the issue seems to have disappeared on its own.

How can I diagnose the issue next time it happens?

Comment: It if happened two days ago it might have been caused by the overload on the Apple servers (macOS checks whether an application is allowed to run when you launch it).

Comment: Yes indeed, it was on Thursday 12th November at 8pm GMT, and other users faced the same problem with Apple Gatekeeper: https://www.msn.com/en-us/money/other/apples-gatekeeper-issues-might-have-slowed-down-your-mac-earlier/ar-BB1aXFjd Can you write an answer?

Comment: This thread has answers to prevent requests to Apple's servers during launch: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406363/what-is-the-best-way-to-block-ocsp-apple-com-on-mac One other solution might be to unplug from the internet while launching the application.