# pf.conf configuration?

Tags: mac, network, firewall, macos

I've been a Windows user for 35+ years and I'm new to Macintosh.

I would like to configure PF firewall to block the ports below, incoming and outgoing on all interfaces.

What commands do I need to use to edit PF and do the commands below look correct? I don't know much about computers so bear with me.

Is it possible to block all incoming connections with pf wall? Or will that result in not being able to connect to any Wifi network?
How does pf wall affect Mac's native built-in firewall? Does PF rules overwrite the built-in firewall?

This could be my `/etc/pf.conf`:

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"

block in quick inet proto { tcp, udp } from any to any port 67,68,22,23,25,88,119,138,139,192,311,389,445,500,515,548,587,626,3283,3285,3689,4500,5009,5223,5350,5351,5353,5900
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the built in firewall and or [LittleSnitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) on macOS and avoid `pf` as you get started on your macOS journey.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210060

You will break a lot of security and other functionality with those rules, but experimentation is always fun. Hopefully someone else has more idea on `pf` specifics if you want to pursue it after getting acquainted with the ports, servers and functions Apple has baked in.

Last time I checked, `pf` got the last word and broke Apple firewall design to allow network extensions and their firewall to manage traffic. We would want to know your exact hardware and os version to go deeper.

Comment: hi mike, in what way will it break security. i was under the impression it would do quite the opposite  ? im on a 2019 16' macbook pro , 1TB , 32GB ram, running Monterey

Comment: How will your machines check [OCSP and certificate validations](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/406381/5472) if you’re blocking traffic to and from apple? How will it validate updates are signed? What’s your plan for MDNS and APNS traffic?